# Understanding and adding to htaccess for redirection

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently we host a number of sites in our hosting account (GoDaddy), each in a different folder. GD told us that we had to assign our main domain to the root of the hosting account, but our main site is in a folder (let's call it 'oursite'). Since we don't want people to have to type www.oursite.com/oursite we have the following redirection rule in htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oursite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!oursite)(.*)$ /oursite/$1 [L]
```

This rewrite rule was added by a previous programmer (he is not with us anymore) and I'm trying to do 2 things:

1) I'm trying to understand what (?!oursite) is doing in the second line. I understand most of the rule but this part I'm not clear about.

2) I'd like to add some rewrite rules in order to make friendly URLs whenever we have URLs with GET queries. Would I be able to do this and keep the above rule working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `(?!oursite)` is **negative lookahead** that means match this pattern `.*` if request doesn't already start with `/oursite`.
2. Yes you can have pretty URL rules with this rule. Better you keep those rules in `/oursite/.htaccess`